# What does the :compiler command do in Vim?

Tags: compilation, command, vim

I recently found that there is a command in Vim called compiler. You can call it with any common compiler (for example, :compiler gcc, :compiler php, etc.), but it doesn't seem to have any immediate effect.

I searched on the manpages but didn't find anything useful about what it actually does, nor does the Vim Wiki. Does anyone know what that command actually does?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sets options for that compiler, such as the program to use for `:make` and the format of error messages so vim can jump you to error locations. Look in `$VIMRUNTIME/compiler/` for the different .vim files that can be sourced.

#### `:help write-compiler-plugin`

> A compiler plugin sets options for use with a specific compiler.  The user can
>   load it with the `:compiler` command.  The main use is to set the
>   'errorformat' and 'makeprg' options.

See also `:help errorformat` and `:help makeprg`.

Here's the GCC compiler file on my machine, for example:

#### /usr/share/vim/vim72/compiler/gcc.vim

```
" Vim compiler file
" Compiler:         GNU C Compiler
" Maintainer:       Nikolai Weibull <now@bitwi.se>
" Latest Revision:  2006-12-20

if exists("current_compiler")
  finish
endif
let current_compiler = "gcc"

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo-=C

CompilerSet errorformat=
      \%*[^\"]\"%f\"%*\\D%l:\ %m,
      \\"%f\"%*\\D%l:\ %m,
      \%-G%f:%l:\ %trror:\ (Each\ undeclared\ identifier\ is\ reported\ only\ once,
      \%-G%f:%l:\ %trror:\ for\ each\ function\ it\ appears\ in.),
      \%f:%l:\ %m,
      \\"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l%*\\D%c%*[^\ ]\ %m,
      \%D%*\\a[%*\\d]:\ Entering\ directory\ `%f',
      \%X%*\\a[%*\\d]:\ Leaving\ directory\ `%f',
      \%D%*\\a:\ Entering\ directory\ `%f',
      \%X%*\\a:\ Leaving\ directory\ `%f',
      \%DMaking\ %*\\a\ in\ %f

if exists('g:compiler_gcc_ignore_unmatched_lines')
  CompilerSet errorformat+=%-G%.%#
endif

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
```

Comment: I wrote a simple c program
ran `:compiler gcc` and `:make %`, I get `make: Nothing to be done for \`dummy.c'.`

Comment: This doesn't seem to set `makeprg`. I don't understand what is the use of this file?

Comment: You need an existing Makefile for default operation mode of `:make` - but you can set up vim to work with without a Makefile - see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Vim typically has a number of common compiler configurations installed, as mentioned, so it will automatically choose the appropriate one. To actually use the compiler configuration you need to use the Vim :make function, as also mentioned, but the default mode of operation expects a `Makefile` to exist.

If you're just trying to do a quick compile on the current file/buffer (without an existing Makefile) then if you have GNU make installed you can just compile it like this (as explained [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make-compile_current_buffer)):

```
:make %:r
```

And it will compile the file and provide vim with the errors/warnings so you can navigate each one using the *quickfix* (`:help quickfix`) list - `:cn` Next error, `:cp` Previous error, `:cw` New window listing errors.

If you don't have GNU make installed you can set this variable - either immediately in the current session like this:

```
:se makeprg=gcc\ -o\ %<\ %
```

Or put it in your ~/.vimrc file:

```
set makeprg=gcc\ -o\ %<\ %
```

Then you can type:

```
:make
```

And it will compile the file and provide you with the *quickfix* list of errors/warnings in Vim.

EDIT: If you also want to run the compiled executable from within vim you can do ('!' executes, '%:r' is the filename without its suffix):

```
 :!./%:r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:help compiler
```

It sets the options for the selected compiler for the current buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit a java file, you can do :compiler javac and then, :make % to compile the current file...